# Mongoose: find() and count() query

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mongodb, mongoose

### Background

I have a query in Mongoose that finds a set of objects, and then returns these said objects together with the total number of them:

```
var itemsPerPage = 4, pageNum = 1;

Survey.find({})
    .limit(itemsPerPage)
    .skip(itemsPerPage * pageNum)
    .then(docs => {
        if (docs.length === 0)
            console.log("There are no results matching your query.");
        else
            DocModel.count({})
                .then(number => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({number, docs}));
                });
        })
        .catch(console.log);
```

To achieve this I do:

1. `find` query with params
2. use `limit` and `skip` to obtain results from correct page
3. if `docs` is not empty, start a `count` query
4. return information

### Problem

The problem here, since I need pagination in the query, is that I have to make 2 separate requests to the DB (`find` and `count`) which can potential be very heavy.

To optimize this, I would like to avoid the `count` query, but I don't know how.

Another issue is the nested promises anti pattern, but that is not the issue I would like to focus on right now.

### Question

I am open to any suggestions on improving this code you may have!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution

After reviewing many answers, I believe I have two options:

1. Make two queries, like I am doing now,
2. Use a pagination plugin for mongoose

My decision was the second one and so I am now using [mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am still using the 2 query method up to now. I wish there was an auto index for this kind of total count.

Comment: This lib `mongoose-paginate` does the same 2 queries: run the query first and again with count.  
```promises = {
      docs: docsQuery.exec(),
      count: this.count(query).exec()
    };
```

Comment: And `count` is deprecated, by the way. Use `countDocuments` or `estimateCountDocuments` if it is a big set. [Mongoose count](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count)